# PyQT6 make verticalScrollBar() QWheelEvent scroll 1 row instead of 3

Tags: python, qt, scrollbar, qtableview, pyqt6

I have a QTableView with a verticalScrollBar()

The problem is that when I use the mouse wheel to scroll down/up it moves 3 rows at a time, I'd like to change this to only move 1 row at a time.

Looking at the class reference it seems to implement QWheelEvent,so my best guess is I must overwrite this event...however I have absolutely no idea where to start.

Any help would be much appreciated!

I'm using Python 3.10.5 and Pyqt 6.3 on Arch Linux (Manjaro)

Comment: Are you using the `ScrollPerPixel` mode or the default `ScrollPerItem`?

Comment: You could just subclass the view, override the `wheelEvent(event)` function, then check the event's `angleDelta()`: based on the y being greater or less than 0, set the value of the scrollbar by it's current value +/- 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `QApplication` class has the [setWheelScrollLines](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qapplication.html#wheelScrollLines-prop) method for setting this property globally. But if you only want it to affect one widget, you can create a subclass and utilise it in a reimplemented `wheelEvent`.

Here's a simple demo:

```
from PyQt6 import QtGui, QtWidgets

class TableView(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        for row in range(100):
            model.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem())
        self.setModel(model)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        lines = QtWidgets.QApplication.wheelScrollLines()
        try:
            QtWidgets.QApplication.setWheelScrollLines(1)
            super().wheelEvent(event)
        finally:
            QtWidgets.QApplication.setWheelScrollLines(lines)
    
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])
window = TableView()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: That did the trick...thanks a bunch!